# Can I mix Apple stock RAM with OWC RAM?

Tags: imac, memory

I have an iMac that shipped with 16GB RAM (using 2 out of 4 slots). I ordered two 16GB RAM modules from OWC. Instead of just replacing the RAM, can I actually add the OWC RAM to what's already in there? Will this cause problems, mixing the two brands?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it will work, although it's always better to have the same latency and MHz kits.

Comment: It should work, **IF** your Mac supports 48GB of RAM. Some do some don't best to check the specs on Apple.com to see. But putting them in to see shouldn't cause any issues.

Comment: I think he means: "Could I just bought 1x 16gb module to add to my existing 16gb to get 32gb?". So he wouldn't need to **replace** his current 16gb with OWC module. I might be wrong..